# ImageButton automatically rotates the selected image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view, android-imagebutton

I don't want to alter the image I select from the gallery in any way. I just want that selected image to display as is in the ImageButton view. Because, if the image gets rotated after selecting it from the phone storage, it gets uploaded to the database in the same state and also gets fetched in the same (rotated) state. Some images rotate, while others don't. Hence, I'm not able to write a generalized code which nullifies the rotation of the selected image.

**activity_post.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".PostActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/post_image_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of **PostActivity.java** related to ImageButton

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton selectCardImage;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);    

        selectCardImage = findViewById(R.id.post_image_button);    
        selectCardImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenGallery();
            }
        });

    private void OpenGallery() {

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to account for `rotation` in images `EXIF` data.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? My images aren't rotated. Some are portrait (vertical) images which get auto-rotated by the ImageButton. `wrap_content` also doesn't seem to work for the `layout_height` of the ImageButton.

Comment: Use [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface) on image you receive in activity result and check TAG_ORIENTATION.